# Instafeed.js not uploading photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instafeedjs

Does instafeed.js only work with an active website? I'm trying to add my friends instagram photos to the website I'm creating for him but the website is not yet 'live/active' so I feel this must be the reason why it's not working.

Does the instafeed.js work in test mode?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var Feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '4950173594',
    clientId: '0a8d7d566c7a4049bdba43a03d1cfd66',
    accessToken: '4950173594.0a8d7d5.b61e3c7e54024b2ca1d3b74399b63d9f',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: 4,
    links: false,
    template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
});


  userFeed.run();

});
```

Comment: Did you get your API client id from Instagram?

Comment: Oh yes, I got the client Id, user id and access token. Does this work in test mode? I don't have an active website to add the instagram feed. I also noticed that the user id number and the beginning numbers of the access token are dif. one is mine and the other is theirs, how would I change that?

Comment: Im not sure what test mode is, but yes, instafeed.js will work if your url is localhost or a purchased domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (or get your client to) log into the Instagram account which you want to grab feeds from.

Visit http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

Authorize the apps to generate the access token.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 'XXXXX',
    accessToken: 'XXXXX.123456789........xyz',
  });
  feed.run();
</script>

<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

`USER_ID` is simply the first few numbers before the dot in your Access Token

XXXXXXXXXX.12345678....

no `client_id` needed

Comment: So I won't be able to generate the token myself, my friend/client has to do it and send it to me? That seems so hard. I mean do all developers have to do that when creating webpage for other and using instagram, twitter feeds on their clients website?

Comment: Yes for many security reasons, the client will have to authorize use of their social media account(s).

Comment: You should be able to use your own instagram account info, fetch your own photos, use that for testing, and styling purposes, so you aren't waiting on your client. Then once your client finishes that task, you can just easily swap out your credentials with theirs.

Comment: thanks, Jon. That makes more sense why it's not working. I was losing my mind trying to figure out they weren't popping up. I'll practice with my own photos for now. Best wishes.